# Find a limit that involves CDF (t distribution)

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, t-distribution

Is there a way to show
$$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}xT_{\nu}(x)=0$$
where $T_{\nu}(x)$ is the CDF of Student's t distribution? Repetitive application of L'Hospital's rule to the fraction $\frac{x}{1/T_{\nu}(x)}$ does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you a hint.

While x/(1/F(x)) doesn't work, does F(x)/(1/x) work?

Comment: It works! Thank you!